# Conformal Mapping $\mathbb{C}\backslash$ $\{z :|Im(z)| \leq -Re(z)\}$ to Upper half plane

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, conformal-geometry

Finding it difficult to find a conformal mapping from the set

$\mathbb{C}\backslash$ $\{z :|Im(z)| \leq -Re(z)\}$

to the upper half plane.

Any advice will be very helpful

I know I can use $f(z) = e^z$ to map the strip $\{z : 0 < Im(z) < \pi\}$ to the upper half plane.

Comment: Avoid no-clue question: [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: Ok I've added what i already know

Answer (score 1):

The region you're describing, when plotted (using Desmos, for example) is

[image]

Let's name it $G$.

The angle between the positive real axis and either edge is $3\pi/4$. We 
can work with the principal branch of the logarithm in $G$ so that we can define $f(z)=z^{4/3}$ in this region through the principal branch of the logarithm (of course).

---

What I mean here is that
$$
  f(z)=\exp\left(\frac{4}{3}\log(z)\right)
$$
where $\log$ denotes the branch of the logarithm defined on the region
$\mathbb{C}\setminus\{z\in\mathbb{C}\colon\:
\mathrm{Re}(z)\leq0\text{ and }\mathrm{Im}(z)=0\}=G_1$.

---

This function maps $G$ conformally onto 
$G_1$. We have now transformed $G$ to $G_1$ conformally. Let's now 
transform $G_1$ to the right half plane 
$G_2=\{z\in\mathbb{C}\colon\:\mathrm{Re}(z)\geq0\}$ conformally. The
function $g(z)=\sqrt{z}$ does the job.

Now transform $G_2$ to the upper half plane through a rotation and we
are done. The conformal mapping we are looking for is given by the
compositions of these maps:
$$
  e^{i\pi/2}(g\circ f)(z)=e^{i\pi/2}\sqrt{z^{4/3}}
$$

Comment: Hey thanks for the response this makes alot of sense. However, the region described is the compliment of the region you plotted. How would I be able to find a map that transforms that to the first quadrant? Thanks again

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I read it wrong. Let me see if I can fix it.

Comment: I had to rewrite the whole answer. You can look at the edit now. :-)

Comment: Hey sorry, a few more questions on this do you mean taking $f(z) = z^{3/4}$ instead , because transforming e.g. $e^{i2\pi/3}$ with your given$ f(z)$ would give $e^{i8\pi/9}$ which gives an $x < 0$ (contradiction). Also, I dont seem to understand the square root and rotating, would you be able to elaborate. Thanks for the time I really appreciate it!

Comment: Don't worry. What I tried to say above is that $f(G)=\mathbb{C}\setminus\{z\in\mathbb{C}\colon\: \mathrm{Re}(z)\leq0\text{ and }\mathrm{Im}(z)=0\}$. Having put it this way, your example doesn't do any harm. For the square-root and rotate part I'll edit my answer, it'll be much easier that way.

Comment: But $z = e^{i2\pi/3} \in G$  However, $f(z) =  e^{i8\pi/9} \implies Re(z) \leq 0 \implies f(z) \not\in f(G)$

Comment: $f(G)$ is the complex plane without the negative real axis. If $z=re^{i\theta}\in G$, then $f(z)$ is on the negative real axis if and only if its argument is $\pi$ or $-\pi$, but the argument of $f(z)$ is just $(4/3)\theta$ which equals $\pi$ or $-\pi$ if and only if $\theta=(3/4)\pi$ or $\theta=-(3/4)\pi$ which is does not happen in $G$. Hope this clarifies our discussion.